# Binomial distribution: How to determine individual P(success) from N and a given CDF(K)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

My real application is probabilistic detection, but it can be conveyed in a simple toy problem (fake numbers as placeholders) ...

A lamp factory uses 1000 individual LEDs in a lamp.  A lamp is bad if more than 50 of its  LEDs are bad.  What is the max allowable failure rate of the individual LEDs if the factory targets a lamp failure rate of 1e-6. (assume i.i.d. LED failure rate).

In other words, for a desired overall failure rate `r`, number of trials `N`, max number of individual failures `K`; I want the individual probability of failure `p` that satisfies `binom(N,p).cdf(K) = 1-r`.

I could bisect the function to find a numerical solution, but I'm hoping for a closed form solution.

Comment: You can approximate the binomial distribution by the normal distribution. Btw, what is your numerical solution?

Comment: That's a good idea if I can assume N,K are fairly large. I'm not sure I can.

Comment: If N is not large you have to calculate the sum. I don't see any other option at the moment. What is you numerical solution?

Comment: re my numerical solution: The function `f(p) = binom(N,p).cdf(K)` is monotonically decreasing with f(0)=1,f(1)=0 for K<N (reasonable in my case).  My current direction is to start with those low,high points and use bisection to halve the uncertainty each iteration.  The curvature can be large, so I'm concerned about even linear interpolation, forget about second order optimization techniques

Comment: I am using `scipy` in Python and `boost::math` in C++ for the actual computation of the binomial CDF -- not sure what they do under the hood.

Comment: May I ask again: What is your numerical solution?

Comment: Do you mean for the explanatory toy problem with fake numbers? umm, .09 approximately solves it : `scipy.stats.binom(1000,.09044).cdf(50) = 1e-6`

Comment: Isn't it $P(X>50)=1e-6$ and not $P(X\leq 50)=1e-6$? I assume that you mean $1e-6=10^{-6}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138127/discussion-between-mark-borgerding-and-callculus42).